# How to ignore newlines when using method skip(String) of the java.util.Scanner object?

Tags: java

I would like to save some time and not manually test each token in a parsed file, but seems I do not know how to correctly use the `skip(String)` method of the `java.util.Scanner` class.

To rephrase the question: how do I make both of the tests below to pass?

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ScannerTest {

    static private final String text = "FUNCTION_BLOCK Unnamed_project\n\tVAR_INPUT\n\t\tUnnamed_variable1 : REAL;\n\tEND_VAR\nEND_FUNCTION_BLOCK"; 

    @Test
    public void scannerSkipTest() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new StringReader(text));
        sc.skip("(?i)FUNCTION_BLOCK");
        String blockName = sc.next();
        assert sc.hasNext("(?i)VAR_INPUT");         // added test
        sc.skip("(?i)VAR_INPUT");                               // line of failure
        String variableName = sc.next();
        sc.skip(":");
        String type = sc.next();
        sc.skip("(?i)END_VAR");
        sc.skip("(?i)END_FUNCTION_BLOCK");

        assert "Unnamed_project".equals(blockName);
        assert "Unnamed_variable1".equals(variableName);
        assert "REAL".equals(type);
    }

    @Test
    public void scannerWithoutSkipTest() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new StringReader(text));
        String skipped = sc.next();
        assert "FUNCTION_BLOCK".equalsIgnoreCase(skipped);
        String blockName = sc.next();
        skipped = sc.next();
        assert "VAR_INPUT".equalsIgnoreCase(skipped);
        String variableName = sc.next();
        skipped = sc.next();
        assert ":".equalsIgnoreCase(skipped);
        String type = sc.next();
        skipped = sc.next();
        assert "END_VAR".equalsIgnoreCase(skipped);
        skipped = sc.next();
        assert "END_FUNCTION_BLOCK".equalsIgnoreCase(skipped);

        assert "Unnamed_project".equals(blockName);
        assert "Unnamed_variable1".equals(variableName);
        assert "REAL".equals(type);
    }
}
```

Any tips and hints appreciated.

Comment: Found out the correct way to do this is to replace all `skip` method calls with `next` without storing the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuto, thanks for editting my answer after you tried it out, I'll take what you wrote and re-write the explanation at the top.

Basically, when looking to skip over a token with `skip()`, you need to skip over the whitespace first. In contrast, the `next()` method does this automatically.

From the javadoc:

*The next() and hasNext() methods and their primitive-type companion methods (such as nextInt() and hasNextInt()) first skip any input that matches the delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next token.*

Therefore, by using `sc.skip(WHITESPACE + "abc")` you can skip over any whitespace and then token `abc`. The result looks like this:

```
public class ScannerTest {

    static private final String text = "FUNCTION_BLOCK Unnamed_project\n\tVAR_INPUT\n\t\tUnnamed_variable1 : REAL;\n\tEND_VAR\nEND_FUNCTION_BLOCK";
    public static final String WHITESPACE = "[ \\n\\t]+";

    @Test
    public void scannerSkipTest() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new StringReader(text));
        sc.useDelimiter(WHITESPACE);
        sc.skip("FUNCTION_BLOCK");
        String blockName = sc.next();
        sc.skip(WHITESPACE + "VAR_INPUT");
        String variableName = sc.next();
        sc.skip(WHITESPACE + ":");
        String typeWithSemiColon = sc.next();
        sc.skip(WHITESPACE + "END_VAR");
        sc.skip(WHITESPACE + "END_FUNCTION_BLOCK");

        assert "Unnamed_project".equals(blockName);
        assert "Unnamed_variable1".equals(variableName);
        assert "REAL;".equals(typeWithSemiColon);
    }
}
```

Note that the scanner still won't split `REAL` from `;` since the semicolon isn't really whitespace - I leave that as an exercice for you to figure out :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I 'll edit the question example by adding one more assert line to the 1st test. to show, that it should pass with the default delimeters.

Comment: Doh, I did not see right away that you added a prefix to all skip patterns. Thanks again for a better work-around.

Answer (score 0):

For reference I am posting a cleaner solution on the original question as well as solving the challenge of semicolon which was exposed by vikingsteve.

Here is the corrected test method.

Note:

- delimiter `\b` surrounded by optional spaces
- using method `next` instead of `skip` for skipping keywords

---

```
@Test
public void scannerSkipTest() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new StringReader(text));
    sc.useDelimiter("\\s*\\b\\s*|\\s+");

    sc.next("(?i)FUNCTION_BLOCK");
    String blockName = sc.next();
    sc.next("(?i)VAR_INPUT");
    String variableName = sc.next();
    sc.next(":");
    String type = sc.next();
    sc.next(";");
    sc.next("(?i)END_VAR");
    sc.next("(?i)END_FUNCTION_BLOCK");

    assert "Unnamed_project".equals(blockName);
    assert "Unnamed_variable1".equals(variableName);
    assert "REAL".equals(type);

    sc.close();
}
```